# Callback URL in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook with my website; I have already created a new app and i have an appid but the problem is; I can't see the option for adding a callback url.

Several people have advised me to check "apps.developers.com" and look for the "my applications tab" but then that's not what i see when i visit that url.

All I see is the "Apps" dropdown menu which when i click only gives me my appname without any option of adding a callback url while on my dashboard.

Comment: You need to give more details: Which SDK are you using, how's your login flow etc. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I am using PHP SDK and also integrate the Facebook login